# 14.04 update hangs on bluez

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, dpkg

I am having trouble doing a software update on 14.04.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The terminal hangs indefinitely after outputting:

```
Setting up bluez (5.23-2ubuntu0trusty1) ...
```

I have tried rebooting the machine, but any further updates are met with this message:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Running:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Results in the same problem:

```
Setting up bluez (5.23-2ubuntu0trusty1) ...
```

Is there a known problem with bluez? Or is there a workaround for problem packages during updates?

Answer (score 0):

1/ Firstly

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

2/ if it does not work:

```
sudo apt-get install -f 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

3/if it does not work:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all --configure -a 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

4/ if it does not work:

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-all bluez 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work; all of the dpkg commands hang indefinitely. It looks like the installation scripts for dpkg have some kind of problem.

Comment: It appears the real problem is a disk failure. Thanks for the pointers though.

Comment: I've installed BlueZ 5.30 from source and found that bluetoothd does not run in the background. It should, which is probably why you are seeing this problem. I haven't found a fix yet.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the code to run bluetoothd as a daemon is missing in the 5.x releases. I just added the code from 4.x and it worked. See the patch below.

```
diff --git a/src/main.c b/src/main.c
index 4c94a69..979521e 100644
--- a/src/main.c
+++ b/src/main.c
@@ -583,6 +583,13 @@ int main(int argc, char *argv[])
                exit(0);
        }

+        if (option_detach == TRUE) {
+                if (daemon(0, 0)) {
+                        perror("Can't start daemon");
+                        exit(1);
+                }
+        }
+
        umask(0077);

        event_loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
```

Comment: So I ran `sudo apt-get source bluetooth` and when into the source directory to modify main.c.  I would then need to compile it and install the package.  Would I have to do this each time there is an update?